# Playing a sound on keypress using React

Tags: reactjs, audio, keyboard

I am not experienced in React so please excuse if this question will seem silly.
I have been trying to play a sound when a key is pressed on the keyboard.

I wanted to use the following solution:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sampler/v/1.0.2

The problem is that when I try to play my sample i get an error:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

```
import React from  'react';
import './App.css';
import Sampler from 'react-sampler';

var samples = [{
    file: "samples/sample1.wav",
    key: 'h', // First sample
    startAt: 0.2 // delay in sec
  },{
    file: 'samples/sample2.wav',
    key: 'o', // Second sample
    startAt: 0.05
  }];
  
  var ReactSamplerExample = () => ({
    
    
    handleSampleLaunch: function(sample){
      var elm = document.querySelector('[data-key='+sample.key+']');
      elm.classList.add('active');
  
      setTimeout(() => { elm.classList.remove('active')}, 150);
    },
  
    render: function() {
      return (
          
        <div>
          <ul className="keys">
            <li data-key="h">
              <span className="key"></span><span className="sample">Sample 1</span></li>
            <li data-key="o">
              <span className="key"></span><span className="sample">Sample 2</span></li>
          </ul>
  
          <Sampler samples={samples} onLaunchSample={this.handleSampleLaunch} disabled={false} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  
  });
```

I checked the path to the files and they seem to be ok (all files are located in the same directory as the samples folder).

I'm not sure how to solve this. If there is a better tool or a simple audio API anyone can recommend or should switch to I would gladly take some advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/uifx or https://www.npmjs.com/package/soundfont-player

Answer (score 0):

You are using react sampler for that. I like to use native html component with some customization for this situation.

Here my sample for you, hope i can help you with this sample:

[Codesandbox Audio Play](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-framework-gqovj?file=/src/App.js)